# Throttle number of concurrent executing processes via buffered channels (Golang)

Tags: go, concurrency, channel

Intent:

I am looking for a means to run os-level shell commands in parallel, but want to be careful to not clobber CPU and am wondering if a buffered channel would fit this use case.

Implemented:

Create a series of `Job`s with a simulated runtime duration. Send these jobs to a queue which will `dispatch` them to `run` over a buffered channel as throttled by `EXEC_THROTTLE`.

Observations:

This 'works' (to the extent that it compiles and runs), but I am wondering if the buffer is working as specified (see: 'Intent') to throttle the number of processes running in parallel.

Disclaimer:

Now, I am aware that newbies tend to over-use channels, but I feel this request for insight is honest, as I've at least exercised the restraint to use a `sync.WaitGroup`. Forgive the somewhat toy example, but all insight would be appreciated.

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/wS_WefJ2vqy)

```
package main

import (
    // "os/exec"
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "strconv"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

const (
    EXEC_THROTTLE = 2
)

type JobsManifest []Job

type Job struct {
    cmd     string
    result  string
    runtime int // Simulate long-running task
}

func (j JobsManifest) queueJobs(logChan chan<- string, runChan chan Job, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    go dispatch(logChan, runChan)
    for _, job := range j {
        wg.Add(1)
        runChan <- job
    }
}

func dispatch(logChan chan<- string, runChan chan Job) {
    for j := range runChan {
        go run(j, logChan)
    }
}

func run(j Job, logChan chan<- string) {
    time.Sleep(time.Second * time.Duration(j.runtime))
    j.result = strconv.Itoa(rand.Intn(10)) // j.result = os.Exec("/bin/bash", "-c", j.cmd).Output()
    logChan <- j.result
    log.Printf("   ran: %s\n", j.cmd)
}

func logger(logChan <-chan string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    for {
        res := <-logChan
        log.Printf("logged: %s\n", res)
        wg.Done()
    }
}

func main() {

    jobs := []Job{
        Job{
            cmd:     "ps -p $(pgrep vim) | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $3}'",
            runtime: 1,
        },
        Job{
            cmd:     "wc -l /var/log/foo.log | awk '{print $1}'",
            runtime: 2,
        },
        Job{
            cmd:     "ls -l ~/go/src/github.com/ | wc -l | awk '{print $1}'",
            runtime: 3,
        },
        Job{
            cmd:     "find /var/log/ -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*[0-9]{10}'",
            runtime: 4,
        },
    }

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    logChan := make(chan string)
    runChan := make(chan Job, EXEC_THROTTLE)
    go logger(logChan, &wg)

    start := time.Now()
    JobsManifest(jobs).queueJobs(logChan, runChan, &wg)
    wg.Wait()
    log.Printf("finish: %s\n", time.Since(start))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, you mean to establish a mechanism to ensure that at any time at most a number of `EXEC_THROTTLE` jobs are running. And if that is your intention, the code does not work.

It is because when you **start** a job, you have already consumed the channel - allowing another job to be started, yet no jobs have been finished. You can debug this by add an counter (you'll need atomic add or mutex).

You may do the work by simply start a group of goroutine with an unbuffered channel and block when executating jobs:

```
func Run(j Job) r Result {
    //Run your job here
}

func Dispatch(ch chan Job) {
    for j:=range ch {
        wg.Add(1)
        Run(j)
        wg.Done()
    }
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan Job)
    for i:=0; i<EXEC_THROTTLE; i++ {
        go Dispatch(ch)
    }
    //call dispatch according to the queue here.
}
```

It works because as along as one goroutine is consuming the channel, it means at least one goroutine is not running and there is at most `EXEC_THROTTLE-1` jobs running so it is good to execuate one more and it does so.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @leafbebop, I will attempt suggested and accept answer once I have this sorted out.

Comment: https://blog.golang.org/advanced-go-concurrency-patterns You may find this blog post helpful.

Comment: Hi @leafbebop. Maybe I'm confused about your comment `//call dispatch according to the queue here.`. I updated the queue to loop until the length of `EXEC_THROTTLE`, but as you can see only the first two `Job`s are run if `EXEC_THROTTLE == 2`. What am I missing? https://play.golang.org/p/Ye35isSP8kv
Also, I think I need to wait for `logger` to return to call `wg.Done()`.

Comment: You indeed missed my point. I changed your code here:https://play.golang.org/p/HhkDh3WYgBH Try to understand it with my explaining in the answer first. I find it hard to explain more but if there is still something unclear, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thank you. The reason I previously felt it necessary to call `run` in a goroutine is that I want to block for the value of `EXEC_THROTTLE`, not each `Job`. As edited, it appeared that each `Job` was running sequentially, rather than executing the first two in parallel, but now from studying your answer I realize that was my misinterpretation because it was sending to `logger`as soon as `run` returned. If I edit any pair of `Job`s to have the same value of `runtime` this it is clear it is executing in parallel. I really appreciate you taking the time to clear this up.

Comment: Also, +1 for the talk by Sameer Ajmani. This is really quite profound and very well done.

Answer (score 4):

You can also cap concurrency with buffered channel:

```
concurrencyLimit := 2 // Number of simultaneous jobs.
semaphore := make(chan struct{}, concurrencyLimit)
for job := range jobs {
    job := job // Pin loop variable.
    semaphore <- struct{}{} // Acquire semaphore slot.
    go func() {
        defer func() {
            <-semaphore // Release semaphore slot.
        }()
        
        do(job) // Do the job.
    }()
}
// Wait for goroutines to finish by acquiring all slots.
for i := 0; i < cap(semaphore); i++ {
    semaphore <- struct{}{}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace processItem function with required execution of your job.

Below will execute jobs in proper order. Atmost EXEC_CONCURRENT items will be executed concurrently.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func processItem(i int, done chan int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) { 
    fmt.Printf("Async Start: %d\n", i)
    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond * time.Duration(i))
    fmt.Printf("Async Complete: %d\n", i)
    done <- 1
    wg.Done()
}

func popItemFromBufferChannelWhenItemDoneExecuting(items chan int, done chan int) { 
    _ = <- done
    _ = <-items
}


func main() {
    EXEC_CONCURRENT := 3

    items := make(chan int, EXEC_CONCURRENT)
    done := make(chan int)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for i:= 1; i < 11; i++ {
        items <- i
        wg.Add(1)   
        go processItem(i, done, &wg)
        go popItemFromBufferChannelWhenItemDoneExecuting(items, done)
    }

    wg.Wait()
}
```

Below will execute jobs in Random order. Atmost EXEC_CONCURRENT items will be executed concurrently.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func processItem(i int, items chan int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) { 
    items <- i
    fmt.Printf("Async Start: %d\n", i)
    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond * time.Duration(i))
    fmt.Printf("Async Complete: %d\n", i)
    _ = <- items
    wg.Done()
}

func main() {
    EXEC_CONCURRENT := 3

    items := make(chan int, EXEC_CONCURRENT)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for i:= 1; i < 11; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)   
        go processItem(i, items, &wg)
    }

    wg.Wait()
}
```

You can choose according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I use this a lot. https://github.com/dustinevan/go-utils

```
package async
import (
    "context"

    "github.com/pkg/errors"
)

type Semaphore struct {
    buf    chan struct{}
    ctx    context.Context
    cancel context.CancelFunc
}

func NewSemaphore(max int, parentCtx context.Context) *Semaphore {

    s := &Semaphore{
        buf:    make(chan struct{}, max),
        ctx:    parentCtx,
    }

    go func() {
        <-s.ctx.Done()
        close(s.buf)
        drainStruct(s.buf)
    }()

    return s
}

var CLOSED = errors.New("the semaphore has been closed")

func (s *Semaphore) Acquire() error {
    select {
    case <-s.ctx.Done():
        return CLOSED
    case s.buf <- struct{}{}:
        return nil
    }
}

func (s *Semaphore) Release() {
    <-s.buf
}
```

you'd use it like this:

```
func main() {

    sem := async.NewSemaphore(10, context.Background())
    ...
    var wg sync.Waitgroup 
    for _, job := range jobs {
        go func() {
            wg.Add(1)
            err := sem.Acquire()
            if err != nil {
                 // handle err, 
            }
            defer sem.Release()
            defer wg.Done()
            job()
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: Your second part of code has unmatched bracelets. I am having trouble to understand how it work so I won't edit for you.

Comment: Ok I get it and fixed it for you. But I would say, it is so over-complicated on such an issue.

Comment: Well, If you're just doing a little playground app, sure. But if you're trying to manage the use of external resources, then it's real nice to just say:
`sem.Acquire()` then `sem.Release()` when using resources. As you've shown above, workers are also a way of solving this problem.

Comment: If the code contains some option for auctual memory management, or capabilities for distributed calculation, I would really appreciate the abstract. But as it is just some wraps around a buffered channel doing basic stuff, the code seem unnature and redunctant to me. But that is a very personal point of view.